# I'm stuck and having trouble with ￢P ∨ Q Prove: P → Q

Tags: logic

I am having trouble with this problem as I have just started doing logic. Is this the same as

> P → Q
>   Prove: ￢P ∨ Q

?

Comment: Which text book are you using? An online proof checker and text book may be helpful as supplementary material: http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Welcome to PSE. The answers hint at how to find a proof. But your question seems to be whether proving  P → Q from ￢P ∨ Q is the same as proving ￢P ∨ Q from P → Q to which the answer is "No, this is not the same thing, though the proofs might *look* (structurally or otherwise) similar".

Comment: The two statements should have the same truth values. Would that analysis assist in showing equivalence?

Answer (score 5):

In a **natural deduction system** (*if that is what you are using*) to prove a conditional, such as is P → Q, you must use a Conditional 
Proof.

This takes the form of assuming the antecedent (that is P) aiming to derive the consequent (that is Q) through valid inferences (also using the premises; that is ￢P ∨ Q). Then discharging the assumption allow the deduction of the conditional (that is P → Q).

Now to prove Q from an assumption of P and the premise of ￢P ∨ Q, either use Disjunctive Syllogism, or a Proof by Cases.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, the two statements are equivalent:
`(￢P ∨ Q) ⊢ (P → Q)` and `(P → Q) ⊢ (￢P ∨ Q)`
are both provably true statements, so `(￢P ∨ Q) ≡ (P → Q)`.

But in order to prove that equivalence, we need to prove both directions separately. To see why, consider the case where instead of `(￢P ∨ Q)` and `(P → Q)`, we have these two statements:

- `P`
- `P ∨ Q`

We can trivially prove that `(P ∨ Q)` follows from `P`; this is more or less the *definition* of the addition rule.  But `P` does *not* necessarily follow from `(P ∨ Q)`, since `(￢P ∧ Q)` also satisfies that clause.  We *can* prove it in one direction, but they are not equivalent statements.

Comment: The two statements are logically equivalent using the material implication rule.  Draw out a truth table and see for yourself that the tables are 100 percent identical.

Comment: @Logikal I know they are equivalent. I *said* they are equivalent.  But the OP isn't asking if they're equivalent; they are asking if, having already proven  A ⊢ B, you must still prove B ⊢ A in order to establish that an equivalence exists.  The answer to that is "yes". The fact that this particular equivalence has already been proven doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

If one uses a truth table generator one can show that (¬P ∨ Q) ↔ (P → Q). To see this, insert the following input into the [Stanford Truth Table Tool](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/): (~P or Q)<=>(P=>Q)

This shows that the two statements are equivalent.

However, the question asks one to *prove* P → Q given the premise ¬P ∨ Q. Here is how one might do this using a [natural deduction proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/):

[image]

See the links below for an explanation of the rules used by this proof.

The proof would not be the same if we wanted to prove ¬P ∨ Q given the premise P → Q. That proof would look like this:

[image]

Although the statements are equivalent based on a truth table generator, the proofs from one to the other may be different depending on which is the premise and which the conclusion.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/